# Virtual Keyboard for multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, virtual-keyboard

I found this virtual keyboard named "simple-keyboard" and it is working only for one input field. Inputs from the keyboard are getting inserted into the 1st text field only.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." class="input">
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." class="input">
<div class="simple-keyboard"></div>
```

Simple-Keyboard JS

```
let Keyboard = window.SimpleKeyboard.default;
let keyboard = new Keyboard({
  onChange: input => onChange(input),
  onKeyPress: button => onKeyPress(button)
});
// Update simple-keyboard when input is changed directly
document.querySelector(".input").addEventListener("input", event => {
  keyboard.setInput(event.target.value);
});
console.log(keyboard);
function onChange(input) {
  document.querySelector(".input").value = input;
  console.log("Input changed", input);
}
function onKeyPress(button) {
  console.log("Button pressed", button);
  // If you want to handle the shift and caps lock buttons
  if (button === "{shift}" || button === "{lock}") handleShift();
}
function handleShift() {
  let currentLayout = keyboard.options.layoutName;
  let shiftToggle = currentLayout === "default" ? "shift" : "default";
  keyboard.setOptions({
    layoutName: shiftToggle
  });
}
```

Source: https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/demos/

How can I make it work for all the input fields with `class="input"` ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `querySelector()` only ever returns a single item matching the selector. If multiple exist only the first is returned.

To fix your problem you need to use `querySelectorAll()`, which provides a collection of all matching elements, then you need to initialise the library on all inputs in that collection by looping through them.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".input").forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("input", event => {
    keyboard.setInput(event.target.value);
  });
})
```

> whenever I try to make an input it enters into the 1st text field only... even though I select the second input field when trying the keyboard... not working

Given that comment it's possible that the library doesn't support multiple controls per instance. Instead you may need to create an entire `Keyboard` instance per control. This also needs to be done within the loop:

```
document.querySelector(".input").addEventListener("input", event => {
  let keyboard = new Keyboard({
    onChange: input => onChange(input),
    onKeyPress: button => onKeyPress(button)
  });
  keyboard.setInput(event.target.value);
});
```

Comment: tried your code... whenever I try to make an input it enters into the 1st text field only... even though I select the second input field when trying the keyboard... not working :(

Comment: In that case you may need to create an entire instance of the `Keyboard` object for every input.

Comment: I found a documentation here... Just trying to understand it.. Can you also have a look ? https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/editor/?d=hodgef/simple-keyboard-npm-demos/tree/uc-multiple-inputs

Comment: Hey @RedStarEntertainment , sorry for the delay, I just found this question on Google. Here's the docs to support multiple inputs https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/questions-answers/use-simple-keyboard-multiple-inputs/ - If you come across any issues feel free to report it in the github repo and I'll respond right away. Thanks!